# R Shiny renderTable not showing in mainpanel without any errors

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that:

1. Let's the user upload a CSV file
2. Displays the data table of the uploaded file by using the `DT` package.

The code does not seem return any errors, however the `mainpanel` is empty as the table is not being rendered.

How can I fix this?

Data:
The data can be downloaded from [here](https://%20%5B1%5D:%20https://app.box.com/s/d5e56io6ym7t0d2hd68ph1pl6nd4d7uv).

Code:

```
    library(DT)
    library(shiny)
    
        options(shiny.maxRequestSize=1024*1024^2)
        ui =   navbarPage(
           # 1st tab
           tabPanel("Regression Analysis",
                    dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", "Please choose a CSV file",
                                                         multiple = T,
                                                         accept = c("text/csv",
                                                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                                                    ".csv")),
                                               tags$hr(),
                                               checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                                               radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                                            choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                                                        Semicolon = ";",
                                                                        Tab = "\t"),
                                                            selected = ","),
                                               radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                                            choices = c(None = "",
                                                                        "Double Quote" = '"',
                                                                        "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                                            selected = '"'),
                                               tags$hr(),
                                               radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                                                            choices = c(Head = "head",
                                                                        All = "all"),
                                                            selected = "all")),
                                  
                    mainPanel(
                        DTOutput("contents")),),
                    actionButton("choice", "Define Regression Variables"),
                    selectInput("independent", "Independent Variables:", choices = NULL, multiple = T),
                    uiOutput("dependent1"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("regTab")))
    
    #Tell the server how to assemble inputs into outputs
        server = function(input, output, session) {
         mydf = reactive({
                
                # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
                # and uploads a file, header of the will be displayed by default,
                # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
                
                req(input$file1)
                
                df = read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                               header = input$header,
                               sep = input$sep,
                               quote = input$quote)
                
                if(input$disp == "head") {
                    return(head(df))
                }
                else {
                    return(df)
                }
                
            })
            
            output$contents = renderDT({ #!!! Table is not showing for some reason
                req(mydf())
                mydf()
            })
       
 }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  Just ensure that all the parenthesis are properly closed.

Comment: Thank you but R is not returning any `parenthesis` `flags` in the code.

Comment: Please ensure your code is syntactically correct before posting your question: Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  <redacted>: unexpected ')'
37:            verbatimTextOutput("regTab")))
38: )
    ^
Warning in readLines(path) :
  incomplete final line found on '/Volumes/Data/Clients/r/test88/Test87/app.R'
Possible extra comma at:
33:                           tableOutput("contents")),),
                                                      ^
Possible unmatched ')' at:
38:)
   ^

Comment: This is the second time in less than 24 hours that code you've posted has been syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @Limey, thank you for pointing that out, please see the updated code now, `R` is not returning any `syntax` errors on my end. I have fairly reduce the code for the purpose of the question.